# How to assign an IP to Flask application running in a Docker container

Tags: docker

I have a simple Flask application that just outputs "Hello world". If I do something like `flask run --host=127.0.0.23 --port=5001` on my host machine, I can ping the app on my browser on the given hostname and port.

However, if I do the same thing when running this app inside a Docker container i.e. I have 
`CMD flask run --host=127.0.0.23 --port=5001` inside my Dockerfile, I cannot ping the application on my host machines browser.

I understand that having `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` inside the Flask app makes it accessible at `localhost:5000` on my host machine. But I want to know if I can access the app using a hostname I assign myself.

Code for Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't "assign an ip" to your application. You publish the port on your host.  That is, if your application listens on port `5000` inside the container, you might run:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 myimage ...
```

This will expose the service on port `5000` of your host, which means that a browser running on your host could access the service at either `localhost:5000` or `<any_address_of_your_host>:5000`, and a browser elsewhere on your network could access the service at `<any_routeable_address_of_your_host>:5000` as well.

There doesn't need to be any correlation between the port on which your application is listening and the port on which you publish it.  E.g., for the above you could instead run:

```
docker run -p 80:5000 myimage ...
```

This would expose your application on port 80 on your host.

Read the [Container Networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) documentation for more information.

Comment: I understand the thing about the ports. What I am trying to do is to run the  Docker container multiple times so I have several instances of the same Flask application running and I want to be able to ping all the different applications on my host browser. I figured if I could somehow assign a separate IP to all the applications inside the different containers, I could access them individually on host machines browser. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: You publish each service on a different port.  Or, you can bind them to three separate addresses on your host if you really insist that they all run on the same port. In either case, the docs to which I linked provide details.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Flask is only accessible from localhost. When you put your app in a container, localhost changes from your host machine (your laptop) to the container. Containers have their own localhosts and your requests are originating from outside the container.

This is analogous to running Flask on your host/laptop and trying to access it from other computers on the wifi network or the public. It would fail similarly.

When you configure Flask to listen to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, it will not just listen to requests originating from localhost, but from the outside as well.

Hope this clarified things a bit.

Answered by: Maxim Orlov
link is here: https://forums.docker.com/t/ip-docker-container-listens-on/92103